# Typescript warning when spreading optional keys

Tags: typescript

Im trying to understand why I get a compiler warning from Typescript when trying to create a new object based on an existing object of the same type.

In the code below you can see that spreading the `key2` value causes the error `Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.`. Although `key2` is optional, i'm spreading the value from `object1` which we know has a `key2` entry.

```
type Test = {
  key1: string;
  key2?: {
    key3: string;
  }
}

const object1:Test = {
  key1: "hello",
  key2: {
    key3: "hi"
  }
}

const object2:Test = {
  ...object1,
  key2: { // error here
    ...object1.key2
  }
}
```

Type error:

```
Type '{ key3?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ key3: string; }'.
  Types of property 'key3' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

I'm just interested in understanding the behaviour here and the best way to handle this sort of situation.

TS Playground link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8BQUoGsIgEYAuKRAJwEsA7AcwG4td8AmAfhM22zxAGYTy1eowC+GMRgDGAeyqIo0gEYArCJODE481JyaESAIgAWEADanpBgDSMezDo275+UYxQOjxGKbPlLV6vZaSDqMAHQR-moaNk4g9uiOUBFhUeoEYXaeIkA

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `key2` is:

```
key2?: {
  key3: string;
}
```

That means `key2` is:

- allowed to be absent
- allowed to be `undefined`
- allowed to be `{ key3: string }` (an object with `key3` property that is is a string.)

What's *not* allowed is an object that has an optional `key3` property.

But if we look at the type of your spread:

```
const a = { ...object1.key2 }
// { key3?: string | undefined; }
```

That's not a valid assignment of the `key2` property because if its an object it *must* also have a `key3` property with a `string` value.

---

To satisfy this interface, you need to prevent creating an object if `key2` is undefined.

One way to do that would be:

```
const object2:Test = {
  ...object1,
  key2: object1.key2 && {
    ...object1.key2
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=15&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8BQUoGsIgEYAuKRAJwEsA7AcwG4td8AmAfhM22zxAGYTy1eowC+GMRgDGAeyqIo0gEYArCJODE481JyaESAIgAWEADanpBgDSMezDo275+UYxQOjxGKbPlLV6vZaSDqMAHQR-moaNk4g9goq0QRhdlAAZOnojlARYVHqKXaeIkA)

Comment: Thanks Alex. I guess i'm just wondering why TS cant understand that the instance of  `object1` that is being spread actually has `key3: "hi"` so isn't undefined.

Comment: Because you declared `object1` to be of type `Test` via `const object1:Test = ...`. This discards any more specific that may have been inferred instead. If you remove that and make it `const object1 = {` instead, your code works as is. https://tsplay.dev/mxB48w. This is because something (in theory) could set `object1.key = undefined` before this spread happens which would be legal according to that type. Typescript is making sure you handle that case.